# How to obtain the below effect in the given activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to obtain the below result.

The background i have an activity but hw can i get the popup view as shown below.

or should i inflate an view and right the whole code there

[image: Desire result]

Hi i have an activity.. on a button click i need to popup a view as below, which will work independently as seperate flow...  how can i achieve it.. if possible can i have a sample to get the 1st popup screen so tat i can handle other views.

How can this be achieved, if its fragment hw can i achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have three method to provide to achieve this effect,but I won't give you sample code,I think try by yourself you can learn more and this is why SOF exists,

1. use [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html),it will be the easiest,you can create your xml layout and use `setView()` for this dialog,and when you want to show it,use `dialog.show()` and `dialog.dismiss()` to dismiss it.
2. use `Fragment` to show as the floating view,[DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) will be best.
3. use [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) to show this view,with it,you can create the xml layout and set it to the popupwindow,then you can show it whenever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create dialog using `AlertDialog.Builder` and then inflate the `View` you are showing in the popupwindow and then set the custom view of `AlertDialog.Builder` as 
`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)`
`builder.setView()`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can Create a Dialog Fragment and display it here a is a [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DialogFragment) to android developer guide for it